# Is this caused by opcache error?php-fpm execute code out of date

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Today I meet a strange question:

our project need to online a new module

when I execute `artisan down` in online environment and visit the site, I found it isn't show the maintenance page, it also show the home page

I check the CheckForMantenance Middleware has aleady add to global route middleware, the `down` file in `storage/framework` is exist

I execute `php index.php` it return the maintenance page, but When I visit the site from `brown` or `curl` it show the home page

I also run in test server and local, it all work well

I add a new route for test middlware, and visit the url used by curl and brown, and result is 404, the route does not found

I think it may be caused by router cache, but there is no cache file on bootstrap/cache or storage/framework, because I `never` open router cache!

I have no idea, so I modify the index file, add write header function at top, and redirect to a error html, the crazy thing happened it also show the home page!!!!!!

What happend? I'm sure the project path is right

Finally I reload the php-fpm and it recovery normal, the maintenance view work, redirect url work, and route normal

I don't understand still now, but I guess it may by caused by opcache?

I open the opcache ext, and use the default setting;

env:

```
laravel: 5.3 
nginx: 1.8.1
php-fpm: 7.0.9 with opcache ext
```

Comment: Sounds like opcache. You need to run `opcache_reset();`, get artisan to do it on down.

Comment: thanks, I will try it

Comment: I guess it caused by opcache too, but I don't understand why, isn't the opcache  check file timestamp every 2s? It should be update

Comment: I just updated code  and miss this problem again, and I call the opcache_reset() function in index , but it useless, I restart php-fpm and it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your fpm logs, usually, something like this will pop up (check debug/log levels) between the notices:

```
[01-Mar-2017 23:59:45] NOTICE: [pool www] child 16951 started
[01-Mar-2017 23:59:48] WARNING: [pool www] child 14754 
  exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 4393.427133 seconds 
  from start
```

You have to disable opcache unfortunately.  I've been seeing this issue since php 5.5 all the way to 7.1 , you will also find these in the error logs:

```
2017/03/02 10:00:24 [error] 30498#30498: *170523 upstream timed out    
   (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, 
   client: 81.243.144.1xx, server: fake.test.pro, 
   request: "POST /api/users/53e4203cfd1c46e08d5b570c2c93ff86/items HTTP/1.1", 
   upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "fake.test.pro", 
   referrer: "http://fake.test.pro/console"
```

In particular with Laravel, but I've also seen it on wordpress installations.  It stops when I disable opcache on all versions of php-fpm

There are bugreports around on this issue but no fixes so far. I always end up doing this :

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=0
```

in /etc/php/7.*/fpm/php.ini files.  Then my application is robust again and it costs us 150ms.  it sucks.